# How to generate form in browsable API without using a serializer_class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Lets assume I've an API that expects a couple GET args: 'foo' and 'bar'. And I haven't defined `serializer_class` due to it isn't tied to any specific model:

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class myAPI(GenericAPIView):    

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        foo = request.GET.get('foo')
        bar = request.GET.get('bar')

        # do something with foo & bar

        return Response({'fooplusbar': _something(foo,bar)})
```

Is there any way to tell to djangorestframework to build the form in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

The Django REST Framework only supports forms out of the box for POST, PUT and PATCH requests.

In those cases, the form is generated from the serializer. There is nothing wrong with defining a serializer which does not return Model objects, nor with using the serializer for form display only, and write e.g. a custom POST handler which does not make use of it. But for Django REST Framework to show a form, you must define a serializer.

It would be quite possible to add support for proper GET forms, but you'd need to extend `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer.render` to add the new form to the context, and write your own templates in `rest_framework/api.html`.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your answer. I've been researching for a while and also i've contacted to django-rest-framework team, all seems that overriding the browsable API template to pass the custom form is the proper way here. Thanks!